# How to do authentication in dropwizard

Tags: java, rest, authentication, dropwizard

I've built a small sample API using drop wizard.

I would like to implement basic authentication for the server. So that when users access the service, the service returns the data based on the user credentials sent with the request.

I went over the documentation for authentication: http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/auth/ but don't quite understand how it would work in an actual running example.

Can someone shed some light on how authentication would work on a url like `/foo/bar/{id}/{username}`?

This is how the method looks like for the above URL at the moment. Notice I am just passing the username as a text and no authentication is done at the moment.

```
@GET
@Path(/foo/bar/{id}/{username})
public Foo getStuff (@PathParam("id") int id, @PathParam("username")) {
   return mydao.getFooFromDb(id,username)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Dropwizard OpenID example](https://github.com/gary-rowe/DropwizardOpenID) I wrote a while back on GitHub.

It provides all the source code you'll need to get it working and should act as a useful starting point for your project.

Comment: Excellent resource. Thanks, I've got it up and running and digging through the code to make sense of how everything works. Might have more questions as my wrap my head around it :)

Comment: Given you other questions, I would pay particular attention to the `@RestrictTo` custom annotation. That should handle your authorization issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you get started as well if you want very basic authentication and authorization with security filters: 
[How to do Basic Authentication of a resource in Dropwizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662871/how-to-do-basic-authentication-of-a-resource-in-dropwizard/20663876#20663876)