# How to authenticate requests for an android app

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I am making an Android app which will fetch data from my API.

First thing my app will do is to let users signin using their credentials.

- My question is does my API need to handle sessions? or should I authenticate the user for every request?
- Will the native android app hold the user credentials on the device and send them along for every request after signing in?
- I am using `Retrofit`.  How would I send user credentials after they have signed in?

Answer (score 0):

This will be a good time to take a deep dive and read into OAuth. Your use case seems to match perfectly. There are 2 main steps you will need: Authentication and Authorization. I have briefly explained them here: [Authentication of a resource in Dropwizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662871/how-to-do-basic-authentication-of-a-resource-in-dropwizard/20663876?noredirect=1#comment30956576_20663876). You can ignore the DropWizard part, the REST concept remains the same. The short version of the description could be like this: A user installs your app on the phone. They authenticate ONCE using their username and password (POST request to your REST over SSL). Your service authenticates the user and return back with a "refresh_token" and an "access_token" which the app saves on its side while you map and save the access_token/refresh_token on service side with the user. With every subsequent request your app is going ot send the "access_token" as a part of "Authentication" header which you, on the serverside, will parse and check if the access_token is still alive (assuming that access_token expires) and if it is alive, then complete the authorization/authentication process. If by any chance, the access token has expired, 401 will be returned back to your app. The app will have to then use "refresh_token" to get a new access_token and once approved with a new access_token (which again ofcourse is mapped on server side to the user's identity) all the subsequent calls will use the new access_token, till the time it expires. This is a simplistic version of OAuth and does not follow the specs to the letter. It's a very basic authentication/authorization flow to get you started. I hope this helps!